# How to get a real-size profile picture from a user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, photo, profile

Having a User ID xUID, i know I can get a profile picture this way:

http://graph.facebook.com/xUID/picture?type=large

The problem is that the picture returned from that URL is not the real size (it's about 200px wide).

I need to get that user picture, but real size.

What i've done so far is:

**1. Getting the user albums**

https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=xToken

**2. Iterating on that, and getting the album that have the type="profile".**

**3. With that Album ID (xAID) I can construct a FQL query:**

```
SELECT pid, object_id, src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id = xAID
```

**4. And getting the profile pictures there.**

**5. I need to iterate and find the lastone uploaded by the user.**

So, this process is complex and time consuming. Is there any better/simpler/faster way to acomplish this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, just did as the question said. Browse the Albums, and getting the first profile picture from there.

The answer from Julio doesn't work becouse it's not possible to include "type" on a WHERE clause, becouse it's not an indexable column.

Answer (score 9):

[http://graph.facebook.com/xUID/picture?width=720&height=720](http://graph.facebook.com/linda.vedestig/picture?width=720&height=720)

Comment: How do you know the real size of the picture before asking for it?

Comment: I believe 720x720 is the maximum at the moment. If you want to know the size in advance, you can do this: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dpicture.width%28162%29.height%28159%29 and specify the minimum size you want.

Comment: thank you have been looking for this for a few days now

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform only one FQL query:

```
SELECT pid, object_id, src_big
FROM photo 
WHERE object_id IN 
  (SELECT cover_object_id 
   FROM album 
   WHERE owner=me() AND type="profile")
```

**src_big** will contain link to profile original source.
If you need to get specific user's profile picture please change **me()** with specific user id.

Answer (score 0):

The cover photo also isn't always the most recent photo, as of a few days ago.

Answer (score -1):

Get cover_object_id:

fql?q=SELECT cover_object_id, type FROM album WHERE owner="userid" AND type="profile"

Get src_big:

fql?q=SELECT pid, object_id, src_big FROM photo WHERE object_id="cover object id obtained above"

img src="src_big obtained above"

This helps in something?

Comment: You can't put "type" on where becouse it's not an indexable column.